# Adding world file to launch gazebo crashes robot model

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently working on getting my car robot to work with Ros2. The current state of the robot can be found here: https://github.com/HarunTeper/CRMCE

I created a urdf for the robot model and implemented the plugins for the gazebo sensors and ackermann_drive. When I try to spawn the robot in an empty world (with the urdf_robot.launch.py launch file), there is no problem and I can control it by sending /cmd_vel commands.

However, when I add the world-file to the command

```
    launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', world], output='screen' ),
```

the robot wheels and steering wheel all reset to the base_link position and don't move. When I remove the world argument again, everything works fine and is shown properly in Rviz and Gazebo.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem or had a similar problem?

I am using Ros2 Foxy with Gazebo11 on Ubuntu 20.04. If you want to replicate it you need to move the sonoma_raceway model to your .gazebo models folder.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381129/adding-world-file-to-launch-gazebo-crashes-robot-model/) by [HarunTeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/76567/harunteper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it. I had to update the parameters in my .world file. Before it was:

```
<physics type='ode'>
  <max_step_size>0.01</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <real_time_update_rate>0</real_time_update_rate>
  <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
</physics>
```

and I changed it to

```
<physics type='ode'>
  <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
  <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
</physics>
```

I don't know why this happened, but this solved it for me. Now all wheels are published properly in Gazebo and Rviz, even when spawned in this world.

---

Originally posted by [HarunTeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/76567/harunteper/) with karma: 13 on 2021-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0